# Sorting elastic hits on 'prefix first' logic

Tags: java, elasticsearch, autosuggest

I wanted to achieve a sorted result set where the terms starting the searched term in the autosuggest appear at the top followed by the ones that 'contain' it somewhetre in text: For Eg:
search term: advocate
results :

advocate x
advocate Yx
some advocate

My result set howvere is giving more score for results that contain that term then the ones tha 'begin with' it.How do I mend this:

**Mapping,js:**

```html
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 39
    },
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "custom_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 40,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "relations": {  
      "properties": {
      "primaryTerm": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fielddata": "true",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "custom_normalizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "entityType": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "custom_normalizer"
      },
      "variants": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fielddata": "true",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "custom_normalizer"
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```html
String query="{"bool": { "should": [ {"query_string": {"query":"advocate","fields": ["primaryTerm" ]}},{"query_string": {"query":"advocate","fields": ["primaryTerm.raw^2" ] } } ]}}";
```

**Result:**
[image]
another:
[image]

**elastic result:**

```html
{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":12,"max_score":6.094379,"hits":[{"_index":"agencyvars","_type":"relations","_id":"qCeqHHgBcFeeTWhjAoua","_score":6.094379,"_source":{"entityType":"Agency","primaryTerm":"ACT ADVOCATES","variants":[]}},{"_index":"agencyvars","_type":"relations","_id":"OyeqHHgBcFeeTWhjJYxu","_score":5.6339674,"_source":{"entityType":"Agency","primaryTerm":"TALWAR ADVOCATES","variants":["TALWAR & ADVOCATES"]}},{"_index":"agencyvars","_type":"relations","_id":"BSeqHHgBcFeeTWhjGIyJ","_score":5.1183944,"_source":{"entityType":"Agency","primaryTerm":"ZEUSIP ADVOCATES LLP","variants":["ZEUS IP, ADVOCATES","ZEUSIP ADVOCATES","ZEUS IP ADVOCATES","ZEUS IP","ZEUSIPADVOCATES LLP","ZIUSIP ADVOCATES"]}},{"_index":"agencyvars","_type":"relations","_id":"3CeqHHgBcFeeTWhjTYyZ","_score":4.6892724,"_source":{"entityType":"Agency","primaryTerm":"MURTI & MURTI ADVOCATES","variants":[]}},{"_index":"agencyvars","_type":"relations","_id":"0SeqHHgBcFeeTWhjjI18","_score":4.4118576,"_source":{"entityType":"Agency","primaryTerm":"ANAND AND ANAND ADVOCATES","variants":["AANAND & ANAND ADVOCATES","NAND AND ANAND ADVOCATES","ANAND & ANAND, ADVOCATES","ANAND & ANAND ADVOCATES","ANAND & ANAND,ADVOCATES","ANAND & ANAND","ANAND&ANAND","ANAND AND ANAND ADVOCAETES","ANAND AND ANAND ADVOCATE","ANAND AND ANANDADVOCATES","AND ANAND ADVOCATES","ANAND & ANAND ADVOCATES.","ANAND AND ANAN","ANAND AND ANAND","ANAND AND ANAND ADVOCATES,","ANAND AND ANAND ADVOCATES.","ANAND AND ANAND , ADVOCATES","ANAND AND"]}},{"_index":"agencyvars","_type":"relations","_id":"2CeqHHgBcFeeTWhjTIyn","_score":3.2560868,"_source":{"entityType":"Agency","primaryTerm":"STAR IP Advocates and IPR Attorneys","variants":["STARIP, ADVOCATES & IP ATTORNEYS"]}},{"_index":"agencyvars","_type":"relations","_id":"3yeqHHgBcFeeTWhjD4uW","_score":2.521993,"_source":{"entityType":"Agency","primaryTerm":"ADVOCATE AND PATENTS & TRADE MARKS ATTORNEY","variants":[]}}]}}#######3
```

***in short the scores are:***

score":5.6339674,"_source":{"primaryTerm":"TALWAR ADVOCATES"}

_score":5.1183944,"_source":{"primaryTerm":"INTELLEXIP ADVOCATES}

score":2.521993,"_source":{"primaryTerm":"ADVOCATE AND PATENTS & TRADE MARKS ATTORNEY}

***PS:A small explanation for the answer would be appreciated since I am new to elastic***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply prefix first logic, you can use [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) along with the `boost` parameter. Try out the below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "advocate",
            "fields": [
              "primaryTerm"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "primaryTerm.raw": {
              "value": "advocate",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67049029",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.0386105,
        "_source": {
          "primaryTerm": "ADVOCATE AND PATENTS & TRADE MARKS ATTORNEY"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67049029",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.08597656,
        "_source": {
          "primaryTerm": "TALWAR ADVOCATES"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67049029",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.07815027,
        "_source": {
          "primaryTerm": "INTELLEXIP ADVOCATES"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

`boost` 2 didn't work in your case as the score of `TALWAR ADVOCATES"` was 5.6339674 and that of `"ADVOCATE AND PATENTS & TRADE MARKS ATTORNEY"` was 2.521993.

When you multiply `2.521993` by 2, you get `5.043986`. Since 5.043986 < 5.6339674, you were not getting your expected search result. Therefore, boost 10 worked for you. However, any boost value greater than 2 will work for you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help but unfortunatly its still showing the same order:

Comment: 1. primaryTerm=ACT ADVOCATES, 
 2.primaryTerm=TALWAR ADVOCATES, 
 3.primaryTerm=ZEUSIP ADVOCATES LLP, 
 4.primaryTerm=INTELLEXIP ADVOCATES, 
 5.primaryTerm=MURTI & MURTI ADVOCATES, 
 6.primaryTerm=V GOPALAKRISHNA ADVOCATE, 
 7.primaryTerm=ADVOCATE AND PATENTS & TRADE MARKS ATTORNEY,

Comment: My query: {"bool": {"should": [{"query_string": { "query": "advocate","fields": [ "primaryTerm"] }},{"prefix": {"primaryTerm.raw": {"value": "advocate","boost": 2 }}}]}}

Comment: I tried it with your data set also, and I am getting the expected search result. What is the score of `ACT ADVOCATES` matching term and `ADVOCATE AND PATENTS & TRADE MARKS ATTORNEY` ? I think you need to increase the `boost` value

Comment: @NitikaJain set the `boost` value to 10, and then try running the query. Let me know what you get in the result ?

Comment: Thank you ! @ESCoder boost 10 worked for me .But out of curiosity i would like to know the reason why boost 2 did not work?